Is it possible that work is being done on an object, it's kinetic energy doesn't changes and still the body is transferred from one point to another?
Recently, I read a book about Electrostatics which stated that "Electrostatic Potential at a point is defined as the work done to move a unit charge from a reference point (generally taken as infinity) to that point without changing it's kinetic energy." The question here is, Is it possible that work is being done on an object, the kinetic energy of object remains constant but the object is transferred from one point to another? (As constant kinetic energy implies constant velocity which further implies zero acceleration which indicates no net force acting on object which in turn follows that object remains at rest).

Objects undergoing zero acceleration need not be at rest (nor can "at rest" even be uniquely defined). Your last sentence is correct up until the last step - constant KE implies constant velocity implies zero acceleration (in the direction of motion) implies no net force (in the direction of motion), but does not imply that velocity=0.

So you're actually inferring that the object must have an initial velocity "v" which remains constant from reference to point where potential is to be calculated ( if the object is initially at rest, it won't be able to move). Am I correct??

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@KunalPrajapat You could assume the object is already moving and never changes KE. But it's really just asking about the initial and final state - if the object is "at rest" at both, the work done is just related to the change in position. It doesn't matter if the object gains and loses KE in between.

No, thats not possible. Work done equals the change in kinetic energy - according to the work energy theorem.
Work beeing done is not possible without a net force by definition, a net force means acceleration hence change of velocity and kinetic energy.
Changing position with constant velocity/kinetic energy is not a problem (Newtons 1. law), and means that no work was done.

I have added a few words to the definition from your textbook.
Electrostatic Potential at a point is defined as the work done by an external force  to move a unit charge from a reference point (generally taken as infinity) to that point without changing it's kinetic energy.
The system under consideration id the unit charge.
It is assumed that the unit charge is subjected to two forces: the force on the charge due to the electric field and the external force on the charge.
If these two forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction then the net force on the charge is zero, this in turn means that the net work done on the charge is zero and hence there is no change in the kinetic energy of the charge.
However, what is important in the definition of potential is the work done by one of the forces - the external force.
Note that you can also define the potential in terms of minus the work done by the force on the charge due to the electric field.
